# Recheck rcp handler after execute

Tags: java, handler, rcp

I’m having an issue with our propertyTester and enabling handlers. The property is areUpdatesAvailable and the handler is enabled when this property is true. After the handler executes the areUpdatesAvailable value becomes false, but how I currently have it set up, it only checks when the selection changes. So if I right click on an item and call the Update handler and then right click on the item again without changing my selection, the update is still enabled because it’s not calling the property tester again. Is there a way to make it check again after the handler has been executed?

```
<handler
      class="com.cerner.automation.touchstone.handlers.UpdateExternalReference"
      commandId="com.cerner.automation.touchstone.workflow.Update">
      <enabledWhen>
           <with
                variable="selection">
                <test
                     property="com.cerner.automation.touchstone.testers.nodeItem.areUpdatesAvailable" value="true" forcePluginActivation="true">
                </test>
                <iterate
                     ifEmpty="false"
                     operator="and">
                     <instanceof
                          value="com.cerner.automation.touchstone.model.ExternalReferenceItem">
                     </instanceof>
                </iterate>
               <test
                forcePluginActivation="true"
                property="com.cerner.automation.touchstone.testers.nodeItem.isInternal"
                value="true">
                    </test>
           </with>
      </enabledWhen>
 </handler>
```

Comment: hi mdamman, if you dont mind can you send me your email id if you are familiar with cerner programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using the requestEvaluation after the handler was complete.

```
final IEvaluationService evaluationService = (IEvaluationService) window.getService(IEvaluationService.class);
        evaluationService.requestEvaluation(property);
```